# Rails - Undefined Method in Staging, but fine in local development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, undefined

I'm working on a project and I added a migration to add a `project_page_description` field to a `Company` Model. When I've ran the migrations,

```
@company = Company.first
@company.project_page_description
```

works locally, but any time I attempt to access `project_page_description` after deploying, I get an undefined method error. Why does it work locally but not remotely?

I've deployed all code so the codebases are identical, I've ran all migrations, I'm using Bundler and Capistrano, and I'm deploying to a CentOS server.

Also, besides stop programming, what can I do to stop this from happening again?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the migrations have not been run. Maybe you ran them using the development environment? Try running them like so: `RAILS_ENV=staging bundle exec rake db:migrate`.

Comment: After migrating successfully, I can see the column in the database, but it still gives me the same `undefined method `project_page_description' for #<Company:0x5811168>`

Comment: Did you restart the server/console after that? The columns are read from the database only once, when the app starts.

Answer (score 0):

Check your bundler groups, application config, and environment initializer files, maybe you have something defined as being development-only and not staging?  Also try opening a console up on staging and trying to manually load and invoke the module that's not found.  Remember that require returns true if the module was not already loaded.

Comment: When I load into development, everything works fine, but when I load "test" (the remote environment), I see that the Company model doesn't have a column called `project_page_description`. When I look at `config/environments/test.rb`, rails is caching classes, but running `sudo touch tmp/restart.txt` from the RAILS_ROOT doesn't fix it